# Return all links on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that contains a large amount of links.

I have integrated a search box for the user to type in the link name, and when they hit the button 'Search', it returns all links that contain what the user typed in:

Here is a section of **HTML** for this page:

---

```
<h4><a href="#" id="Trig16">First Header</a></h4>
<div class="slider" id="Slide16">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/TestDocument.doc" target="_blank">Document 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/TestDocument2.doc" target="_blank">Document 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/TestDocument3.doc" target="_blank">Document 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h4><a href="#" id="Trig19">Second Header</a></h4>
<div class="slider" id="Slide19">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="~/Docs/Document4.pdf" target="_blank">Document 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Docs/Document5.pdf" target="_blank">Document 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the **JavaScript** for that button:

---

```
$("#ButtonSearch").click(function () {
    var textboxValue = $("#SearchLink").val().toLowerCase();
    $('.slider').each(function () {
        var exist = false;
        $(this).find('ul li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('a').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textboxValue) !== -1) {
                $(this).show();
                exist = true;
            }
            else
                $(this).hide();
        });
        if (exist === false) {
            $(this).prev('h4').hide();
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).prev('h4').show();
        }
    });
});
```

---

Now I also have a clear button.. and when the user hits that button I want all sliders, headers, ul's, li's, and links to return without a page refresh.

Here is what I have so far for that button:

---

```
$("#ButtonClearSearch").click(function () {
    $("#SearchLink").val("");
    $('.slider').each(function() {
        $(this).prev('h4').show();
    });
});
```

---

So just as an example.. if I were the user and typed in `Document 1` into the search box.. and hit search, it would return the header `First Header` and underneath would be the `Document 1`.

Now if I hit Clear search.. it would return me all of my `h4` elements, but nothing underneath them, except for the `First Header` element with the `Document 1` underneath.. So it is keeping the original search and just returning the rest of the `h4` elements..

So my question is how do I return everything on click of the clear search button?

Comment: `$(this).siblings('h4').show()`

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb That still only returns the `h4` elements.. with nothing underneath them.  The only `h4` elements that have stuff under them are the `h4` elements that contained the links that the user searched for

Comment: Wrap the h4's and the div's in div's and then toggle the wrapper divs.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb can you show some code? or a fiddle?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I have put the `h4`'s and `div`'s into container divs and it is still not working

Comment: I'm working on a fiddle, please wait...

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I have posted my answer. I have it figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out, using what I already have:

```
$("#ButtonClearSearch").click(function () {
    $("#SearchLink").val("");
    $('.slider').each(function() {
        $(this).prev('h4').show();
        $(this).children().each(function () {
           $('ul li').show();
           $('a').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will filter in realtime on keypress or paste. As your user types things into the search if the link contains the text it will hide links that do not contain the text and it will show links that do. As the value changes it will show or hide based on the value of the search.

Edit: Search is now bound to buttton

```js
let filter = function(){
  
  $filter = $('#search-filter').val();
  
  $.each($('a'),function(k,v){
    
    let heading = '#'+$(v).closest('div').attr('data-bind');
    let sibs = $(v).parent().siblings();
    
    if(v.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf( $filter ) > -1){
      //Show
      $(v).closest('li').show();
    }
    else {
      //Hide
      $(v).closest('li').hide();
    }
    
  });
}

$('#searchBtn').on('click',filter);

$('#clrBtn').on('click',function(){
  $("#search-filter").val("");
  filter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-filter"> <input id="searchBtn" type="button" value="Search"> <input id="clrBtn" type="button" value="clear">

<h4 id="Trig16">First Header</h4>
<div class="slider" id="Slide16" data-bind="Trig16">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/TestDocument.doc" target="_blank">Document 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/TestDocument2.doc" target="_blank">Document 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/TestDocument3.doc" target="_blank">Document 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h4 id="Trig19">Second Header</h4>
<div class="slider" id="Slide19" data-bind="Trig19">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="~/Docs/Document4.pdf" target="_blank">Document 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Docs/Document5.pdf" target="_blank">Document 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to return everything on button click.. I do not need this in real-time. I like your solution but it is not one that I am looking for.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Oh no worries. I edited the post so its now bound to a search button and it also has a binding for a clear feature. Are you looking to have it hide the headings with no results also?

Comment: I have posted my answer.  I have figured this out.  Thank you for your help.